# Unity + Android + UART ( rs232 / FTDI / bluetooth )

Tags: android, unity3d, bluetooth, rs232, uart

Микроконтроллер передает по UART данные с датчиков.
Требуется визуализировать показания в виде шкалы приборов на Android устройстве.
К микроконтроллеру подключаю FTDI ( rs232-USB ) // либо hc-06, в случае с BLUETOOTH
Протокол передачи самодельный.

Проект создал в Unity.
Для начала выбрал платформу Windows.
Организовал чтение SerialPort через функцию ReadByte, так как в Unity "кастрированная" библиотека SerialPort.
API = .NET Standart 2.0
Теперь проект хорошо работает под Windows, но мне нужен Android.

Сменил платформу под Android.
Получил кучу ошибок связанных с пространством имен.
Сменил API на .NET 4.x - ошибок не стало.
Скомпилировал APK и запустил на Андроиде.
Для подключения использовал USB-OTG.
Но данные не приходят.

Стал разбираться и понял, что Unity не очень то приспособлена для Android.
Unity выбрал из-за за удобства работы с графикой.
Пришлось учится писать на C#, до этого знал только assembler для AVR Atmel.
Сейчас склоняюсь что нужно было учить JAVA и использовать другую среду типа Processing или AndroidStudio, но мне совсем не хочется переписывать весь проект.

Может быть можно что то сделать в Unity ?
Я находил платные плагины и библиотеки, но я не уверен, что они смогут работать с функцией ReadByte, как требуется в моем проекте..

Я уверен, что ничего сложного в этой задаче нет.
Сложность для меня заключается в непонимании того, что нужно сделать.

Может быть у кого то есть проект на Unity для Android, в котором реализован прием данных с USB или Bluetooth?
Я выяснил, что требуется правка файла Manifest и res/xml/accessory_filter.xml
А где бы подглядеть код на C# ...